# Azure SQL Server - Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to log in to **Query Editor** in the Azure online portal. For some reason I have the below message under the Active Directory authentication area:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

I can still log in using SQL server authentication and I can log in using SSMS from my local machine using Active Directory credentials.

[Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eWJR.png)

Can someone surmise why I am getting this error?

Comment: Does AD account has 2-factor authentication enabled? Authentication won't work for those accounts.

Comment: Are you following the steps provided on the following documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-portal#connect-using-azure-active-directory?wt.mc_id=MVP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set the AD admin account like this tutorial [Configuring an Active Directory (AD) administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-portal#connect-using-azure-active-directory) do:

[image]

When we using the Query Editor(preview), it will shows your AD authentication account:
[image]

Just click the '`continue as **@****.com`', Query Editor will login your database with AAD authentication.

Hope this helps.